# Не закрытый тег <p>

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Есть код:

```
string html = "<div class=\"outer\"><p>текст<p></div>";

HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

var result = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//div[@class='outer']/p");

Console.WriteLine(result.InnerText);
```

Из-за не закрытого тега `p` происходит исключение, т.к `result` равен `null`. Если тег закрыть, т.е `<p>текст</p>`, то всё нормально.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить? Просто получаю html страницы одного сайта, и там в одном блоке `div` весь текст такого вида: `<p>текст<p>другой текст</p>`

Comment: `string[] res = result.InnerText.Split(new [] { "<p>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: Кстати у меня спокойно отработал ваш код, а если вставить туда `<p>текст<p>другой текст</p>` и заменить `SelectSingleNode` на `SelectNodes`, то я без проблем получаю два `p` с нужным текстом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, у меня `SelectNodes` стоит, просто когда создавал тему, почему то написал `SelectSingleNode`. С этим вариантом `string[] res = result.InnerText.Split(new [] { "<p>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` первый `<p>` пропускается.

Comment: Делайте нам самодостаточный пример, который покажет проблему, на данный момент - [не воспроизводится](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oPT4IJ)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, прошу прощения за тревогу. Как раз сидел делал пример, оказалось у меня `HtmlAgilityPack` был версии `1.8.8`, обновился и всё ок. Спасибо за помощь.